# {{ defineZone "brand"}} Where is Brand defined from?

Tags: wso2, wso2-iot

Working on some simple white lable stuff for EMM  and cannot change the Enterprise Mobility Manager label in the header.

Referring to {{ defineZone "brand"}} within the header hbs but need to locate the reference is loaded from?

Any help would be great! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The zone "brand" is defined as a unit (`uuf.unit.header.logo`) [logo.hbs](https://github.com/wso2/carbon-device-mgt/blob/master/components/device-mgt/org.wso2.carbon.device.mgt.ui/src/main/resources/jaggeryapps/uuf-template-app/app/units/uuf.unit.header.logo/logo.hbs). The logo referred can be seen in *../public/img/logo.png* in the same unit.

The product name is overridden in the unit (`mdm.unit.ui.header.logo`) as seen [here](https://github.com/wso2/carbon-device-mgt-plugins/blob/master/components/mobile-plugins/mobile-base-plugin/org.wso2.carbon.device.mgt.mobile.ui/src/main/resources/jaggeryapps/devicemgt/app/units/mdm.unit.ui.header.logo/logo.hbs). You can change the product name by changing the above file.

Comment: Thanks. Appreciate the answer!